# Sum of residuals in constrained linear regression

Tags: regression, residuals, constrained-regression, constraint

Does sum of residuals == 0 hold even if we add ordinality constraints for the coefficients in a regression model?

It would be great if someone can point out to any literature (paper/presentation/discussion thread) on this

Comment: Why not work through a simple example?  Let me suggest this one: fit a linear function $y=a + bx$ to the points $(x,y)$ in $(0,0),(1,-1)$ with the constraint $a\le b.$